# ¿Cómo puedo redirigir a los usuarios al inicio de sesión en Laravel, una vez que se haya expirado el tiempo de inactividad?

Tags: laravel

Al pasar el tiempo de inactividad la aplicación debería redirigir al inicio de sesión, pero lo redirige a una ruta home inexistente.

Esto es lo que tengo en el *.env*:

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=15
SESSION_DOMAIN=
```

y este es el archivo *Authenticate.php*

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
    use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
    
    class Authenticate extends Middleware
    {
        /**
         * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return string|null
         */
        protected function redirectTo($request)
        {
            if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
                dd($request);
                return route('login');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Necesitamos ver como controlas las sesión y la duracion de esta no ?

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas por defecto la authenticacion de laravel debes editar el middleware ubicado en /App/Middleware/Autenticate

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

    class Authenticate extends Middleware
    {
        /**
         * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return string|null
         */
        protected function redirectTo($request)
        {
            if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
                return route('login');
            }
        }
    }
```

donde route('login') es el nombre de la ruta a redirigir si el usuario no a iniciado sesion o esta expira

Comment: Feliz año a todos, gracias BioDark por tu respuesta, el archivo que me comentas lo tengo idéntico al que muestras en tu respuesta y siempre que se expira la sesión me envía a otra pagina.